# Finding videos in iCloud

Tags: video

Do the videos you take on iPhone go to the iCloud? If so where do I find them on my computer? It didn't go where my pictures are.

Comment: How do I get a 2minute video to my computer?

Comment: I want to be able to email it but my phone won't let me without shortening it.

Answer (score 4):

No they don't get moved to the iCloud. At least not automatically. There is a feature called [Photo Stream](http://www.apple.com/icloud/features/photo-stream.html) which does exactly that with photos. But there isn't a Video Stream (yet).

<sub>Note that iCloud *backups* do backup your videos (and hence go to iCloud), however, they are not user accessible (except in restoring an iDevice).</sub>